# This problem is from the error if I sync the gradle to my flutter project in adroid studio

Tags: java, flutter, gradle

'/path/to/jdk-11' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)' this is the error that has been displayed if I sync the gradle in my android studio. Can you please help me solve this problem?